# How to see all events on systrace android profiler?

Tags: android, performance, systrace, android-profiler, perfetto

I think, Whoever has worked with the stack trace, can help me?

I'm trying to analyze my systrace, to find the causes of frozen frame issues.

I see this - https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/inspect-traces#events-table

where all call for a selected thread is shown, and I think, It'll be helpful.

[image: All calls for a threadin systrace]

But I can't see it my systrace, How can i enable it?

[image: My systrace All events are not there]

Answer (score 0):

The Events tab should appear after you selected one or more threads.